# Diagnose NullReferenceException in the finalizer thread

Tags: c#, oracle, iis, idisposable, finalizer

Our IIS hosted WCF application is crashing periodically, showing the following in the application event log

```
Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
Stack:
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.Dispose(Boolean)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.Finalize()
```

this is Oracle.DataAccess 4.121.2.0, i highly doubt that this is an Oracle bug, but rather that we are somehow corrupting the state of the OracleDataReader.

Can someone give a hint on how to diagnose this issue?

Comment: Could be a bug though. There is a general rule: no exceptions in the finalizer regardless of which state the object is in. However, it's suspicious that the finalizer is called for this `IDisposable`. Somewhere, this object is not being disposed and then gets garbage-collected. Make sure it is in `using`s or gets `Dispose()`d.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I have the same problem. I have noticed that the OracleDataReader dispose method is hides the Base implementation rather than overrides it which makes my using statements rather pointless. I'm not entirely convinced that's the issue though. So many things use OracleDataReader it seems like the problem may be else where.

Comment: Sadly not, is getting reported occasionally in production went the route of changing our architecture to recover from a complete IIS restart.

Answer (score 1):

In our case we enable trace logging in `app.config`or `web.config` like this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="All" propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="xml" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
            <listeners>
                <add name="xml" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="myUserTraceSource" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
                <add name="xml" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\Temp\WcfTrace.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Now you can have a look at `WcfTrace.svclog` file and see lots of trace messages that should lead to your error.